# Selecting pandas records from one dataframe and appending to another

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to append a value to a pandas dataframe in a new column. This value will be an identifier that will be the same for all rows, it will come from another pandas dataframe, where it is also the same for all rows.

Example as follows, imagine I have the following starting dataframe:

|  | C | EN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | name |
| B | 123 | name |

Plus the main dataframe,

|  | col | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | d1 | abc |
| 1 | d2 | def |
| 2 | d3 | ghi |

I want to append the values in columns C and EN (123 and Name) as above:

|  | col | col2 | C | EN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | d1 | abc | 123 | name |
| 1 | d2 | def | 123 | name |
| 2 | d3 | ghi | 123 | name |

I believe I want to extract values of "123" as a variable, then I want to extract "ABC" as a variable and then somehow append/join to the main dataframe. However I am getting a lot of Nan type errors. Any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is the `concat` function:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1).ffill()
```

For documentation see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html).

If you only want to append certain columns I believe you can do something like:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2.reset_index(drop=True)[["C", "EN"]]], axis=1).ffill()
```

Thanks to Anurag Dabas for the `.ffill()` option.
Thanks to U11-Forward for pointing out the different index.

Comment: That doesn't give the correct result tho, it gives: 5 rows.

Comment: I think that ffill() is also needed along with concat

Comment: @U11-Forward No it should not, with the `axis=1` it concat's the columns, not the rows.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see the different index... You are right

Comment: Since both answer looking same so I think this should also work `df2.join(df1.reset_index(drop=True)).ffill()`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean by:

```
print(pd.concat([df2, df1.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1).ffill())
```

Comment: Thanks all, this works very well and is close to what I am looking for. The new data frame includes the columns and the values that I wanted, however there are two rows carried from dataframe1, which are NAN for all columns apart from the C, EN columns above. I’m sure there’s an easy way to delete these two rows, but if there was a way to stop them appearing initially that would be helpful.